# Split a string containing consecutive commas plus comma wrapped in quotation marks

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split a string that contains consecutive commas as well as a comma wrapped in quotation marks but can't quite get the result that I want. Here is an example of a string I have:

`var str = ‘10,Apple,"Sweet Gala apple, from Australia",,,,,,in stock,3.99’`

where the third element has a comma inside quotation marks, followed by multiple commas.

I want to split the string by commas under two conditions: 1) don't split the comma that's wrapped inside quotations marks 2) between the multiple commas that are next to each other should be treated as a blank space

When I use the regex below:

```
str.match(/(".*?"|[^,]+)/g)
```

The result comes out to the array below which meets the first condition but fails to insert a blank space between the consecutive commas

```
["10","Apple",""Sweet Gala apple, from Australia"","in stock","3.99"]
```

I want it to look like:

```
["10","Apple",""Sweet Gala apple, from Australia"",'','','','','',"in stock","3.99"]
```

What do I need to do to meet the above two conditions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem here is that you want zero-length matches *under certain conditions*, but the engine will always try to get a zero-length match no matter whether the last item matched ends at the same index (like `10,` will match 10, and if the pattern permits an empty match, then will try to match the empty string between 10 and `,`). A plain global match alone won't be able to differentiate between that and the `,,,,,,` situation.

I'd use `split` instead, rather than `match` - split on a comma, and negative lookahead for non-`"` characters, followed by `",`, to ensure that the comma matched was not within a `""` sequence:

```js
var str = '10,Apple,"Sweet Gala apple, from Australia",,,,,,in stock,3.99';
const result = str.split(/,(?![^"]*",)/);
console.log(result);
```

If the `""`s may come at the very end, then at the end of the negative lookahead, alternate the `,` with `$`:

```js
var str = '10,Apple,"Sweet Gala apple, from Australia",,,,,,in stock,3.99,"foo, bar"';
const result = str.split(/,(?![^"]*"(?:,|$))/);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was change your regex to use `*` instead of `+` like so:

`str.match(/(".*?"|[^,]*)/g)`

Comment: This results in `["10", "", "Apple", "", ""Sweet Gala apple, from Australia"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "in stock", "", "3.99", ""]`, which is not the desired output - the problem is, like I said in my answer, the engine won't be picky about matching zero-length matches when it can.